# Help to plot a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I would like to plot the surface

```
$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\ z=xy\}$
```

for an exercise of affine geometry but I am a novice in graphics!
Can I use GeoGebra? or TikZ or Asymptote?

Comment: Yes, you can use GeoGebra! It has export to PSTricks code, TikZ code or export as a graphics in pdf, eps or png format.

Comment: @matth: except that to plot 3d surfaces, he would need Geogebra 5, and as far as I can tell, it does not support exporting as a graphics yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `pgfplots` package at will. Please check [the manual](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for lots of  other possibilities such as view angle, shader types etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\addplot3[surf,shader=faceted] {x*y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This 3D plot is in orthographic projection. Is perspective view also possible with pgfplots?

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn: No, pgfplots can't do perspective plots yet. You might want to take a look at PStricks for that.

Comment: Many thanks percusse, I will try your code with Texgraph too:

Answer (score 2):

You can also use asymptote, the following will produce the plot you want:

```
import graph3;
import grid3;
import palette;

currentprojection=perspective(12,23,1.5);

size(400,300,IgnoreAspect);

defaultrender.merge=true;

real f(pair z) {return z.x*z.y;}

surface s=surface(f,(-1/2,-1/2),(1/2,1/2),50,Spline);

draw(s,mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())),mean(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow())));

grid3(XYZgrid);
```

[image: 3d plot produced by asymptote]

Another advantage of using asymptote is that if you produce a pdf by running
`asy -f pdf yourfile.asy`, and view it in Adobe reader, it will render the
actual 3d model, and you will be able to rotate it, zoom in and out, change the
way it is displayed, etc.  You can then include the 3d model in your LaTeX document usingthe `movie15` package.

Another option is Metapost with the `mp-solid` module.  There is a documentation (in French) and number of examples [here](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/poulecl/mp-solid/).

Comment: To keep the separate PRC 3D file for later inclusion, asy option `-k` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

run with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or with `xelatex` (that takes some time)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=60 20 15 rtp2xyz,Decran=70,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-6)(5,8.7)
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!10](-4,-6)(5,8.7)
 \psSurface[ngrid=.2 .2,incolor=yellow,linewidth=0.3pt,
 axesboxed,algebraic,hue=0 1](-2,-2)(2,2){ x*y }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Herbert! I will try also the following: \begin{texgraph}[name=surface,export=tkz]
 viewDir(-30,60), view(-5,5,-6,5), view3D(-2,2,-2,2,-4,4),
 BoxAxes3D(LabelSize:=tiny), FillColor:=lightblue,
 Dsurface(M(u,v,u*v), -2+2*i,-2+2*i)
\end{texgraph}